# Probability that a query is wrong given results are correct

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

This question might be practically useless but I'm trying to work through a thought experiment here.

Lets say I have a query that I run on a monthly basis and I want to know if the query is written properly, meaning it returns all the desired results. Now lets say I have hand checked the results for 5 out of 24 months and found the results to be correct.

Basically how can I say with certainty that given the information I have now is correct that all other information I have not checked is also correct. This I think should not be 100% because anaomalies can occur that might cause a result to be omitted and or duplicated.

Thank you,

Comment: How did you choose those five months?

Comment: there was no selection criteria, I just pointed at the screen and took the month my finger landed on. So Random.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator, I think your questoin is related to empirical risk minimization. You can read about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_risk_minimization

Comment: That's not actually random.  At best it could be said to be arbitrary.  Although you can apply statistical techniques to assess the results, they would be questionable.  Not that it would matter much: finding 100% accuracy in just five instances gives little confidence that all 24 instances are 100% accurate. You could get potentially more useful results by making more precise observations of the query results and making specific assumptions about how errors can occur.

Comment: I think this depends an awful lot on how complicated the response of the query is.  If it is supposed to be a number 0 or 1, you have OK evidence that it might be right.  However, if it is a 20 element array of floating point numbers and a sentence of English, then 5 correct would give you much, much better confidence.